# Image while hovering a link [HTML+CSS]

Tags: html, css

So I want to be able to have a link which when hovered, display an image..
So far, I only found tutorial to change an image while it's hovered..

How should I do that please ? 
BTW : I'm a total beginner in HTML..

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you, please do your best to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem and what you have attempted so far to solve it. As it stands, this question will not be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property.

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href='http://example.com'>Hover Here</a>
<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png' width='200'>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery for life.

```js
$('.link').mouseover(function() {
  $('.dog').show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.dog').hide();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
 .link {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Raleway;
}
.dog {
  background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/opKg3fyqWt4/hqdefault.jpg');
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='link'>
  <a href='http://www.google.com'>Hover me</a>
</div>


<div class='dog'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is couple ways to achieve what you want. probably if you are a beginner in html and css, the best for you is to use *zer00ne* snippet. Hovever, if you want to dig deeper I also have the following solution for you:

You can test it here
https://jsbin.com/barixeqigi/17/edit?html,css,js,output

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="super eye" alt="super eye">
  hover
</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
  position:relative;
}
a:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity:0;
  background: url('http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute:
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    transition: all 3s;
}
a:hover:after {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

Comment: Wow that's really neat !